# Alter array object using loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var arr = [{id:1,"name":"John"},{id:2,"name":"James"}]

$.each(arr, function(){
if(this.id == 1){
//change john to Johnathan
}
});
```

without using key, is it possible to alter array object?

Comment: Do you mean without using `this.name = "Jonathan";` ? It isn't possible.

Comment: yes is it possible, you can change `key's value with out changing keys`, hence the object is changed

Comment: @SkyFang the key, `id` is involved in your example.

Comment: Can you explain WHY you can't just do obj.name?

Comment: @Yatrix http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31353930/alter-array-object-property-then-save-back-to-localstorage

Answer (score 0):

You do like this in the loop:

```
var arr = [{id:1,"name":"John"},{id:2,"name":"James"}]

$.each(arr, function(){
if(this.id == 1){
this.name = 'Johnathan';
//change john to Johnathan
}
});
```

Comment: Why is this better than `this.name = 'Johnathan';`?

Comment: @OSDM http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31353930/alter-array-object-property-then-save-back-to-localstorage

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can do that by converting the object to a string if you are looking for a hack.  What is it that you are looking to do?

```
var arr = [{id:1,"name":"John"},{id:2,"name":"James"}]

$.each(arr, function(i){
     if(this.id == 1){
         arr[i] = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this).replace("John", "Johnathan"))
     }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think of would change all "John" values to "Johnson" *in all properties* without explicitly using a property name. You can loop all properties on an object.

```
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    for (var prop in object) {
        if (object.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
            if (arr[i][prop] === 'John') {
                arr[i][prop] = 'Johnson';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This probably won't work for you, but it's the only way to grab a value on an object without using the property name explicitly.

Comment: what I want to achieve is actually this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31353930/alter-array-object-property-then-save-back-to-localstorage

Answer (score 0):

then i think you need to **replace whole array's object with having id == 1**

here is what i tried

```js
for(var i = 1;i<arr.length;i++){
if(this.arr[i].id == 1){
 
  this.arr[1] = {'id':'1','name':'Johnathan'};

}
```